# Assign Function Type to variable with generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete

I have an already declared function type with generics which i want to assign it to a named arrow function. Here's a code example:

```js
import { AutocompleteProps } from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

const itemToString: AutocompleteProps<
  T,
  Multiple,
  DisableClearable,
  FreeSolo
>['getOptionLabel'] = (i) =>
  (typeof i === 'string' ? i : (i?.name as string)) || '';
```

But typescript warns me that it cannot find `T, Multiple, DisableClearable, FreeSolo` generics.

Could you please tell me where should I define them?

Edit: I want this function to be passed to `getOptionLabel` prop of an `Autocomplete` component call and inherit his generics(again sorry if I phrased it incorrectly). Is this possible or should I go with [Rajiv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865531/5510189)

Edit2: Also something like this (which is pretty close to what I want to do) does not work

```
const itemToString: <
  T extends Entity,
  Multiple extends boolean,
  DisableClearable extends boolean,
  FreeSolo extends boolean
> AutocompleteProps<
  T,
  Multiple,
  DisableClearable,
  FreeSolo
>['getOptionLabel'] = (i) => (typeof i === 'string' ? i : (i?.name as string)) || '';
```

Answer (score 2):

so here all the arguments need some value

`T`: shape of the option object.
`Multiple`: boolean value whether you're using AutoComplete for multiple values or not.
`DisableClearable`: boolean value Whether input can be cleared or not.
`FreeSolo`: boolean value to decide whether user input is not bound to provided options.

So based on your requirements you can provide value. I've added an example interface for demo.

```js
import { AutocompleteProps } from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

interface IOption {
  label: string,
  value: string,
}

const itemToString: AutocompleteProps<
  IOption,
  false,
  false,
  false
>['getOptionLabel'] = (i) =>
  (typeof i === 'string' ? i : (i?.name as string)) || '';
```

Comment: This wasn't my question but I understand your confusion because I didn't phrase it correctly. Nevertheless you gave me a viable alternative and thank you for that!

Comment: which version of mui are you using? v4 or v5.
It looks like v4, but wanna make sure

Comment: I am using Material UI v4